# How to load a sparse dataset into XGBoost in Python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

I have a very large sparse dataset with english feature names, as shown below. How do I load this into XGBoost for training a model ?

Based on what I have tried till now, XGBoost can only accept numerical feature names. Is there any way in which XGBoost can accept english feature names, train the model and then give me a capability of seeing the feature importance by name ? I can always create a map of feature names to feature ids to hack around this issue, but I was wondering if there was a simpler way out ?

Dataset

```
1 age:21 weight:56
1 age:32
0 height:46 age:44
0 weight:36 height:99
```

Comment: Take a detour with [sklearns dictVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html).

Comment: @sascha Thanks. Will this ensure that the same feature id (integer) is generated for a feature , say "age", during data generation in training and testing phase. My concern is that a feature name maps to some feature id , say F, during training phase and is embedded in the model. Now, if the same feature is not mapped to the same feature id F in testing phase, then the model won't be able to use that feature. Does that make sense ?

Comment: What would be the purpose of this tool if it didn't obey that rule? :-) You ```fit``` the dictVectorizer on your data (including all possible features) and use ```transform``` to prepare data with this mapping. Multiple uses of ```transform``` will be coherent when fitted once! Just have a look at the docs and maybe test on small handcrafted examples.